New route does not re-render NextJs
I have the following search bar at the top of my app that routes to my /search/[searchId].js page:
    <Link href={`/search/${search}`}>
        <button type='submit' className='btn-cta btn-3'>SEARCH</button>
    </Link>

It routes to this page fine but when I input a new search from on the same page the query isn't updated.

can you show what your [searchId].js file looks like?

    useEffect(() => {
        if (searchId) {
            // Enter your search function here
        }
    }, [searchId]);

